# Total cross-section for Bhabha scattering

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, probability, singularities, scattering-cross-section

The Bhabha scattering differential cross section is given by
$$\frac{d\sigma}{d\Omega}=\frac{\alpha}{2s}\left(\frac{3+\cos^{2}\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\right)^{2}$$
where $\theta$ denotes the angle of the outgoing states. However, the total cross section, obtained by integration over all angles diverges. Why is this so?

Comment: All scattering cross sections between pointlike charged particles diverge at $\theta=0$, because the long distance interaction scatters every particle in the beam, no matter how far away it is.

Answer (score 6):

> However, the total cross section, obtained by integration over all angels diverges. Why is this so?

The total cross section is infinite because the interaction has infinite range and does not fall off "fast enough." The interaction falls off quite slowly (as $1/r$) which is not fast enough to make the total cross section finite.

Remember that the total cross section is basically a measure of the size of the scatterer, which has no sharp boundary in this case since the "size" is determined by the range of the coulomb potential.

---

N.b., this is not some esoteric effect due to Quantum Field Theory. It is rather banal. The same thing happens in single-particle non-relativistic scattering off a fixed coulomb potential.

Comment: It's not even a quantum mechanical effect.  The same kind of divergence shows up in the Rutherford cross section, whether the Coulomb interaction attractive or repulsive.

Comment: @hft: in the lab, would you really measure such an undefined total cross section?

Comment: @Yair: in the lab, would you really perform totally unscreened Bhabha scattering?

Comment: ....in the lab, would your detector really be capable of integrating over the entire solid angle?

Comment: Anyways. The answer is no, you would never measure infinity "in the lab." But nevertheless the total cross section is infinite.

Comment: @hft: In principle, let us assume that one can build an ideal detector, then the result clearly must be a finite number. The fact that we find infinite shows that the current formalism is uncapabale of producing sensible results.

Comment: @hft: by the way, i actually plan to propose a new formalism in which this problem is cured, and the result is finite.

Comment: Problems that do not exist are certainly easy to cure.

Comment: @hft There is certainly a serious problem if you cannot come up with a predictive finite number that matches with the experimental results. It is simply a bad way of thinking to be convinced that this divergence is 'supposed to be there'. There is actually a very deep reason way this happens, but of course, you won't believe me until I shall provide a proof.